# TypeError: 'Meeting' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Al ejecutar el siguiente código me sale TypeError: 'Meeting' object is not subscriptable

```
from datetime import datetime

class Meeting:
    def __init__(self, start_time, end_time):
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time


def check_availability(meeting, proposed_time):
    result_1, result_2, result_3 = False, False, False
    while True:
        if proposed_time < meeting[0][0] or proposed_time > meeting[0][1]:
            result_1 = True
        if proposed_time < meeting[1][0] or proposed_time > meeting[1][1]:
            result_2 = True
        if proposed_time < meeting[2][0] or proposed_time > meeting[2][1]:
            result_3 = True
        if result_1 and result_2 and result_3 is True:
            print(True)
            break
        else:
            print(False)
            break


meetings = [Meeting(datetime(2018, 8, 1, 9, 0, 0), datetime(2018, 8, 1, 11, 0, 0)),
            Meeting(datetime(2018, 8, 1, 15, 0, 0), datetime(2018, 8, 1, 16, 0, 0)),
            Meeting(datetime(2018, 8, 2, 9, 0, 0), datetime(2018, 8, 2, 10, 0, 0))]

print(check_availability(meetings, datetime(2018, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0)))
print(check_availability(meetings, datetime(2018, 8, 1, 10, 0, 0)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `meeting[0]` obtienes el primer elemento de tu lista *meeting*, que es un objeto de la clase `Meeting`. No puedes ejecutar `meeting[0][0]` para obtener el *tiempo inicial*,
tendrías que usar `meeting[0].start_time`.

De la misma manera, en vez de utilizar `meeting[0][1]` para obtener el *tiempo final* debes utilizar `meeting[0].end_time`.

```
from datetime import datetime

class Meeting:
    def __init__(self, start_time, end_time):
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time


def check_availability(meeting, proposed_time):
    result_1, result_2, result_3 = False, False, False
    while True:
        if proposed_time < meeting[0].start_time or proposed_time > meeting[0].end_time:
            result_1 = True
        if proposed_time < meeting[1].start_time or proposed_time > meeting[1].end_time:
            result_2 = True
        if proposed_time < meeting[2].start_time or proposed_time > meeting[2].end_time:
            result_3 = True
        if result_1 and result_2 and result_3 is True:
            print(True)
            break
        else:
            print(False)
            break


meetings = [Meeting(datetime(2018, 8, 1, 9, 0, 0), datetime(2018, 8, 1, 11, 0, 0)),
            Meeting(datetime(2018, 8, 1, 15, 0, 0), datetime(2018, 8, 1, 16, 0, 0)),
            Meeting(datetime(2018, 8, 2, 9, 0, 0), datetime(2018, 8, 2, 10, 0, 0))]

check_availability(meetings, datetime(2018, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0))
check_availability(meetings, datetime(2018, 8, 1, 10, 0, 0))
```

Pero si quieres acceder a los atributos de tu clase `Meeting` de la forma que propones, debes definir el méto `__getitem__` de tu clase de la siguiente forma:

```
class Meeting:
    def __init__(self, start_time, end_time):
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item == 0:
            return self.start_time
        elif item == 1:
            return self.end_time
```

De este modo , siendo `meeting[0]` un objeto de la clase `Meeting`, `meeting[0][0]` es igual a `meeting[0].start_time`, y `meeting[0][1]` es igual a `meeting[0].end_time`.

Finalmente, si utilizas `print` sobre tu función `check_availability`, no deberías usar `print` dentro de la función (en este caso la función devuelve `None`, que se imprimirá). Puedes o bien ejecutar la función fuera de un `print` o sustituir `print(True)` por `return True` (los mismo para `print(False)`).

Un saludo.